# Connection Failed loop with GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I been getting an error trying to execute this Android Drive API  example [googledrive/android-quickstart](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart), the app run fine then shows a windows dialog to select the google account, I select one and in logcat I get this:

```
I/drive-quickstart﹕ GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{44c22a28: android.os.BinderProxy@44c1b1c0}}
```

Then shows the dialog again seems like a infinite loop

I have been already configured the OAuth and other parameters in google developer console.

Here is my code Thanks in advance..

```
public class CloudPaintActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = "drive-quickstart";
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR = 2;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 3;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Bitmap mBitmapToSave;

/**
 * Create a new file and save it to Drive.
 */
private void saveFileToDrive() {
    // Start by creating a new contents, and setting a callback.
    Log.i(TAG, "Creating new contents.");
    final Bitmap image = mBitmapToSave;
    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                    // If the operation was not successful, we cannot do anything
                    // and must
                    // fail.
                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Failed to create new contents.");
                        return;
                    }
                    // Otherwise, we can write our data to the new contents.
                    Log.i(TAG, "New contents created.");
                    // Get an output stream for the contents.
                    OutputStream outputStream = result.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();
                    // Write the bitmap data from it.
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapStream);
                    try {
                        outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Unable to write file contents.");
                    }
                    // Create the initial metadata - MIME type and title.
                    // Note that the user will be able to change the title later.
                    MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                            .setMimeType("image/jpeg").setTitle("Android Photo.png").build();
                    // Create an intent for the file chooser, and start it.
                    IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                            .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                            .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                            .setInitialDriveContents(result.getDriveContents())
                            .build(mGoogleApiClient);
                    try {
                        startIntentSenderForResult(
                                intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Failed to launch file chooser.");
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        // Create the API client and bind it to an instance variable.
        // We use this instance as the callback for connection and connection
        // failures.
        // Since no account name is passed, the user is prompted to choose.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
    // Connect the client. Once connected, the camera is launched.
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    // if the api client existed, we terminate it
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE:
            // Called after a photo has been taken.
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Store the image data as a bitmap for writing later.
                mBitmapToSave = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR:
            // Called after a file is saved to Drive.
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Image successfully saved.");
                mBitmapToSave = null;
                // Just start the camera again for another photo.
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE),
                        REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        // show the localized error dialog.
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
        return;
    }
    // The failure has a resolution. Resolve it.
    // Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, and an
    // authorization
    // dialog is displayed to the user.
    try {
        result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.i(TAG, "API client connected.");
    if (mBitmapToSave == null) {
        // This activity has no UI of its own. Just start the camera.
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE),
                REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
        return;
    }
    saveFileToDrive();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you don't need multiple accounts:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private static final int REQ_CONNECT = 1;

  private Activity mAct;
  private static GoogleApiClient mGAC;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    mAct = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (bundle == null) try {
      mGAC = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Drive.API)
        .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
          @Override public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) { }
          @Override
          public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
            Toast.makeText(mAct, "bingo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  // connected
            saveFileToDrive();
          }
        })
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
          @Override
          public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connResult) {
            if (connResult != null) {
              if (!connResult.hasResolution()) {
                int errCode = connResult.getErrorCode();
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errCode, mAct, 0).show();
                return;
              } else try {
                connResult.startResolutionForResult(mAct, REQ_CONNECT);
                return;
              } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
            finish();  //--- FAIL - no resolution ---------->>>
          }
        })
        .build();
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {  super.onResume();
    mGAC.connect();
  }
  @Override
  protected void onPause() {  super.onPause();
    mGAC.disconnect();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int request, int result, Intent data) {
    switch (request) {
      case REQ_CONNECT:
        if (result == RESULT_OK)
          mGAC.connect();
        else
          finish();  //--- FAIL, user cancelled  ------------->>>
      break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(request, result, data);
  }
}
```

If you need to switch multiple accounts, add:

```
.addApi(Plus.API)
```

to your builder and call:

```
Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGAC);
```

from wherever (menu for instance). Then create a new instance of mGAC and connect. It will pop up the account selection dialog again. But your app will not know which account the user selected (or created).

If you need to know your current user, you can drop the the *Plus.API* and manage the GooDrive accounts yourself with Account Picker, but you need to implement an Account Manager and instantiate *mGAC* with

```
.setAccountName([ACCOUNT EMAIL])
```

as seen [here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/spjanson/gdaademo/MainActivity.java) (follow the *REQ_ACCPICK* and see the Account Manager *UT.AM*).

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Based off your error, it seems for whatever reason it fails to sign in. I believe in this case you should check if [`hasResolution`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult#hasResolution()) returns true. If so, you can call  [`startResolutionForResult`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#startResolutionForResult(android.app.Activity, int)) which will prompt the user to sign in.

As far why it fails to sign in, it's a bit difficult to tell. It sounds like you're using the `AccountPicker`? Perhaps you can try with only a single account signed into the device.

Answer (score 0):

I have observed the behavior you describe when the OAuth 2.0 client ID set up on the Google Cloud console did not match the apk I was trying to run, either by Signing-certificate fingerprint or by Package name.